# Python vectorize function and calling save_dictionary issue

Tags: python, function, vectorization

I am working on creating a vectorize function that does the following.

Take a string argument as the path (folder) to where the text data files are;
Process all data files in the path and produces TF and DF statistics;

I fixed up the code some from my last submission and was wondering how I would Call the save_dictionary() function to save the document's dictionary with TF (term frequencies) to a file, where the filename should be tf_DOCID.txt in the same path.

```
class Document: 
    def __init__(self, doc_id):
        # create a new document with its ID
        self.id = doc_id
        # create an empty dictionary 
        # that will hold the term frequency (TF) counts
        self.tfs = {}

    def tokenization(self, text):
        # split a title into words, 
        # using space " " as delimiter
        words = text.lower().split(" ")
        for word in words: 
           # for each word in the list
           if word in self.tfs: 
               # if it has been counted in the TF dictionary
               # add 1 to the count
               self.tfs[word] = self.tfs[word] + 1
           else:
               # if it has not been counted, 
               # initialize its TF with 1
               self.tfs[word] = 1

def save_dictionary(diction_data, file_path_name):
    # print the key-values pair in a dictionary
    f = open("./textfiles", "w+")
    for key in diction_data: 
        f.print(key, diction_data[key])
        f.close()

def vectorize(data_path):
    Document = []
    for i in range(1, 21):
        file_name = "./textfiles/"+ i + ".txt"
        # create a new document with an ID
    Document = Document(i+1)
        #Read the files
    f = open(Document)
    print(f.read())
        # compute the term frequencies
    Document.tokenization(file_name)
        # add the documents to the lists
    Documents.append(Document)
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to declare an array in this line:    Document[]. But you don't do it this way, its documents = [], you dont declare the typing explicitly in python .

Comment: Your class name is document not Document. And use can use Counter to get frequency of word rather than using a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have little gaps in python. Didn't went into the class implementation but here are some remarks:
be aware that you in tokenization you are passing only the path but in the method using it as the text of the file, you first need to open file path and read its content.

```
def vectorize(data_path):
    documents = [] # No need to declare the type of the array
    for i in range(1, 21):
        file_name = "./textfiles/"+ i + ".txt"
        # create a new document with an ID
    doc= Document(i+1) # Initiation
        # compute the term frequencies
    doc.tokenization(file_name)
        # add the documents to the lists
    documents .append(doc) # appending a current document to documents array
```

Oh and obviously please change the class name to Document as goes pep8 convension
you can look more here: 
[pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

About save_dictionary func: I would  make it a method of  Document class.
and use json to save it to a file:

```
import json
def save_dictionary(self):
    # print the key-values pair in a dictionary
    with open(f'somepath/tf_{self.id}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(self.tfs))
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed up a lot of the issues I was having and updated the question to be a little more accurate of what I am trying to do. I need to call the save_dictionary function to save the documents tf to a new file. How would I go about doing this.

Comment: @gravity00 updated the answer :). Please consider choosing as the write answer

Answer (score 0):

Check the vectorize function:
1) Document is not defined
2) I assume you want to create an empty list: `document = []`